# How to save layers in a group as one image in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I am dealing with large number of layers in photoshop. How can I save multiple layers of a group as a single image in a batch process?

Comment: If you have any of the Photoshop CC versions, there is a built in [asset generator.](https://github.com/adobe-photoshop/generator-assets/wiki/Generate-Web-Assets-Functional-Spec#getting-started) You just name your group something like: `picture.png` and it'll be [exported as such](https://github.com/adobe-photoshop/generator-assets/wiki/Generate-Web-Assets-Functional-Spec#where-does-the-output-go), the next time you save the psd.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. You could right click your groups in the layers menu and **Convert
   smart object**
2. Open all of your Smart object
3. Run batch on all of your open files

Comment: Will this allow OP to work with specific layers within the group that have been converted to a  Smart Object?

Comment: Yes if you create the smart object with the specifc layers selected.

Comment: Excellent - will have to have a play with Smart objects.